# Django - saving over ImageFile appends upload path to filename

Tags: django, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to resize an `ImageField` image and overwrite the existing file. I'm using Django 3.1.2 and Pillow 8.0.0. When I save the updated image, its `upload_to` path seems to get *prepended* to the existing file path. I don't know why it's doing that, and I want it to stop.

The field is defined as:

`hero_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="images/articles/hero")`

Here's a reproducible example of what's happening:

```
from my_app.models import Article
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from six import BytesIO

# load an Article
article=Article.objects.get(id=6019)

# get its image
article.hero_image
> <ImageFieldFile: images/articles/hero/park_lake_5.jpg>

# open the image 
image_file = Image.open(article.hero_image)

# resize the image 
image_file_fit = ImageOps.fit(image_file, (100,100), method=Image.LANCZOS)

# create a stream
image_content = BytesIO()

# save updated image to stream
image_file_fit.save(image_content, format="JPEG", quality=80)

# create a new image file from the stream
new_image_content = ImageFile(image_content)

# save the new image content into the existing image field
article.hero_image.save(article.hero_image.name, new_image_content)

# inspect the updated image
article.hero_image
<ImageFieldFile: images/articles/hero/images/articles/hero/park_lake_5.jpg
```

What's going on? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [`save`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/6599608c4d0befdcb820ddccce55f183f247ae4f/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L86-L87) calls [`generate_fieldname`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/6599608c4d0befdcb820ddccce55f183f247ae4f/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L308-L320) which prepends `upload_to`. Not sure what a better way to update images might be. Can't you assign it to `article.hero_image`, like `article.hero_image = new_image_content`?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why it was doing this, but I eventually worked around it by simply calling [basename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) on the save call, e.g:

```
article.hero_image.save(basename(article.hero_image.name), new_image_content)
```